# How to render to Dom API Array from res.json?

Tags: json, dom, cheerio

I got some data (articles) from website after scraping with cheerio. I can see it as json file on terminal.
How can I render it to Dom? How can get to see it on the console on the browser?
It's a simple app with only index.js file and at the moment.
Thanks!

I have console log it to terminal like so:

```
    res.json(articles);
    console.log(articles)
```

index.js looks like this:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const app = express();
const webpages = [{
        name: "ynet",
        address: "https://www.ynet.co.il/sport/worldsoccer",
}]

const articles = [];

webpages.forEach(webpage => {
    axios
        .get(webpage.address)
        .then((res) => {
            const html = res.data
            const $ = cheerio.load(html)
            $('div.slotView', html).each(function () {
                const title = $(this).text();
                const url = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
                const img = $(this).find('img').attr('src')
                articles.push({
                    title,
                    url,
                    img,
                    source: webpage.name
                });
            });
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json(articles);
    console.log(articles) 
})


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server runnig on PORT ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added an app.js file, querySelector the id from div HTML file, and fetched it like so:

```
const ynet = document.querySelector('#ynet');

fetch('http://localhost:8000/ynet')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        data.forEach(element => {
            const item = `<a href = "${element.url}" target="_blank"><div class="wrapper"><h3>` +
                element.source +
                `</h3><p class="text">` +
                element.title +
                `<img src="${element.img}" alt=""></p></div ></a>`
            ynet.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", item)

        });

        console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```